# How to send html content with xml/json request in rest api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am writing a restful service to send the email in spring boot. 
API request is mapped with object.
When I am sending xml in request it works fine but in body I want to send HTML content.

```
Below is the request without html
    <mailContent>
        <from>abc@gmail.com</from>
        <to>
                <email>xyz@gmail.com</email>
        </to>

        <subject> MY ALERT </subject>
        <contentType>multipart/mixed</contentType>      
        <body>
            Hi Raj \n
            How are you?
        </body>
    </mailContent>
```

With HTML

```
    <mailContent>
        <from>abc@gmail.com</from>
        <to>
                <email>xyz@gmail.com</email>
        </to>

        <subject> MY ALERT </subject>
        <contentType>multipart/mixed</contentType>      
        <body>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
</body>
</html>
        </body>
    </mailContent>
```

Controller

```
public SendMailResult sendMail(@ApiParam("Contains the mail content and configurations to be used for sending mail") @Valid @RequestBody MailMessage message, BindingResult result) throws InterruptedException {

        SendMailResult results = new SendMailResult();
        message = sendemailService.prepareMessage(message);

....
}
```

When I add HTML in XML it fails to map request with the object.

Answer (score 0):

as you are sending html data, xml will consider each tag as its own, so to avoid this, try sending html data in another tag of xml with double quotes like:

 "Page Titlebody {  background-color: lack;  text-align: center;  color: white;}

## This is a Heading

This is a paragraph.

"